# Getting 1005 constraint error on create table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

I am making a script that reading some php files creates a SQL file. I have almost finished, but I am getting a MySQL error that I can't figure it out :(

This is the SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Id único de cada tag',
  `name` VARCHAR(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Nombre de la tag',
  `id_user` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Id del usuario',
  `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT 'Fecha de creación del registro',
  `updated_at` DATETIME NULL COMMENT 'Fecha de última modificación del registro',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_tag_user_idx` (`id_user`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tag_user` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Id único de un usuario',
  `user` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Nombre de usuario',
  `pass` VARCHAR(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Contraseña del usuario',
  `num_photos` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Número de fotos de un usuario',
  `score` FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Puntuación del usuario',
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Usuario activo 1 o no 0',
  `last_login` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT 'Fecha de la última vez que inició sesión',
  `notes` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Notas sobre el usuario',
  `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT 'Fecha de creación del registro',
  `updated_at` DATETIME NULL COMMENT 'Fecha de última modificación del registro',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

There are more tables, but these are the first two and it already crashes with:

```
#1005: Can't create table `tag` (Error: 150)
```

The script starts with `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` and ends with `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Create the `user` table first. It has to exist so the other table can refer to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is of ordering of query, look into this line:

```
KEY `fk_tag_user_idx` (`id_user`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tag_user` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

here you are referring to the table `user`, which is not created so far as the query to create `user` is below and which runs after first query.

So create the `user` table first and then `tag` table.

Comment: Thanks, that was it... I thought setting foreign key check to 0 disabled ALL relation checks and as the table user was created inmediately after when I set it back to 1 it would all work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

As Said, create `user` table first, or, if it's a problem, create all the tables without Foreign Key constraints and update them after all the create tables